# Android check Internet connection automatically

Tags: android, connection, wifi, 3g, disconnection

Hello world how to always detect if I am connected or disconnected from the Internet automatically.
Example: When I connected and I turn off 3G or wifi the toast says I'm disconnected, 3 seconds after I activate the 3G or wifi and a toast tells me I am connected.

I use this method but it tells me the state of the connection at startup of the application but not during navigation in the application.

```
 ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

//For 3G check
    boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .isConnectedOrConnecting();
//For WiFi Check
    boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            .isConnectedOrConnecting();


    if (!is3g && !isWifi)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Network Connection is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Network Connection is ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `utility` class and `BroadcastReceiver`  for this purpose. Below link shows show step by step procedure

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Timer`'s schedule to run a thread. Notice the last `3000` which will make it run every 3 seconds.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        //For 3G check
        boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .isConnectedOrConnecting();
        //For WiFi Check
        boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            .isConnectedOrConnecting();


        if (!is3g && !isWifi)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Network Connection is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Network Connection is ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}, 0, 3000);
```

Comment: Nice solution. Exactly what I need!

Comment: I got "Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" error

Comment: @A.Najafi The error message is a tad misleading. What you're doing is calling it from a worker thread. You need to call your Toast from within the main thread

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use this method anywhere you like :)

```
 public static boolean isDeviceOnline(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isOnline = (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    if(!isOnline)
        Toast.makeText(context, " No internet Connection ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return isOnline;
}
```

Inside Your activity use this code:

```
activity=this;
if(isDeviceOnline(activity))
 {
 //you are online
 }
 else
 {
 //you are offline
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `BroadcastReceiver`!
You get notified everytime your `network connectivity` change from WIFI/3g/ON/OFF..

Look here: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

And here: http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-getting-notified-of-connectivity-changes/

Answer (score -2):

```
private boolean checknet(){

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetworkinfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return activeNetworkinfo != null && activeNetworkinfo.isConnected();
    }

//write below methodcall in every button click event wherever u want to check internet connection


 if(!checknet())
        {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connecction.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question you still might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users.